# Javascript Export from Fiddle

Tags: javascript

https://betterprogramming.pub/implementation-of-zoom-and-pan-in-69-lines-of-javascript-8b0cb5f221c1

Towards the bottom of this article, there is a codepen/fiddle like environment that has several files that when I download onto my local or my server, it doesn't work even though no external files or libraries are used (apparently).  Can anyone help me figure out what I need to do to export this and use it outside of the example pen/fiddle?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you downloaded the project, the online code editor, in this case did not include a link to the script files nor the CSS, let alone the body or defining it even was a HTML document. This is because editors such as codepen/jsfiddle inject code into an existing HTML template which is normally displayed along side the editor.

Anyway, after sorting out and re-organising the files, I linked the necessary files and removed the unnecessary JS modules, which was only converted as such simply by the code editor.

Below is only the files you would need, the JSON package was uneeded, up to you, you should be able to add/edit anything from now onwards. Simply copy each section of the snippet below into the corresponding HTML, CSS, JS files.

```js
    const hasPositionChanged = ({ pos, prevPos }) => pos !== prevPos;

    const valueInRange = ({ minScale, maxScale, scale }) => scale <= maxScale && scale >= minScale;

    const getTranslate = ({ minScale, maxScale, scale }) => ({ pos, prevPos, translate }) =>
        valueInRange({ minScale, maxScale, scale }) && hasPositionChanged({ pos, prevPos })
            ? translate + (pos - prevPos * scale) * (1 - 1 / scale)
            : translate;

    const getMatrix = ({ scale, translateX, translateY }) => `matrix(${scale}, 0, 0, ${scale}, ${translateX}, ${translateY})`;

    const getScale = ({ scale, minScale, maxScale, scaleSensitivity, deltaScale }) => {
        let newScale = scale + (deltaScale / (scaleSensitivity / scale));
        newScale = Math.max(minScale, Math.min(newScale, maxScale));
        return [scale, newScale];
    };

    const pan = ({ state, originX, originY }) => {
        state.transformation.translateX += originX;
        state.transformation.translateY += originY;
        state.element.style.transform =
            getMatrix({ scale: state.transformation.scale, translateX: state.transformation.translateX, translateY: state.transformation.translateY });
    };

    const canPan = (state) => ({
        panBy: ({ originX, originY }) => pan({ state, originX, originY }),
        panTo: ({ originX, originY, scale }) => {
            state.transformation.scale = scale;
            pan({ state, originX: originX - state.transformation.translateX, originY: originY - state.transformation.translateY });
        },
    });

    const canZoom = (state) => ({
        zoom: ({ x, y, deltaScale }) => {
            const { left, top } = state.element.getBoundingClientRect();
            const { minScale, maxScale, scaleSensitivity } = state;
            const [scale, newScale] = getScale({ scale: state.transformation.scale, deltaScale, minScale, maxScale, scaleSensitivity });
            const originX = x - left;
            const originY = y - top;
            const newOriginX = originX / scale;
            const newOriginY = originY / scale;
            const translate = getTranslate({ scale, minScale, maxScale });
            const translateX = translate({ pos: originX, prevPos: state.transformation.originX, translate: state.transformation.translateX });
            const translateY = translate({ pos: originY, prevPos: state.transformation.originY, translate: state.transformation.translateY });

            state.element.style.transformOrigin = `${newOriginX}px ${newOriginY}px`;
            state.element.style.transform = getMatrix({ scale: newScale, translateX, translateY });
            state.transformation = { originX: newOriginX, originY: newOriginY, translateX, translateY, scale: newScale };
        }
    });

    const renderer = ({ minScale, maxScale, element, scaleSensitivity = 10 }) => {
        const state = {
            element,
            minScale,
            maxScale,
            scaleSensitivity,
            transformation: {
                originX: 0,
                originY: 0,
                translateX: 0,
                translateY: 0,
                scale: 1
            },
        };
        return Object.assign({}, canZoom(state), canPan(state));
    };



  const container = document.getElementById("container");
    const instance = renderer({ scaleSensitivity: 50, minScale: .1, maxScale: 30, element: container.children[0] });
    container.addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
        if (!event.ctrlKey) {
            return;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        instance.zoom({
            deltaScale: Math.sign(event.deltaY) > 0 ? -1 : 1,
            x: event.pageX,
            y: event.pageY
        });
    });
    container.addEventListener("dblclick", () => {
        instance.panTo({
            originX: 0,
            originY: 0,
            scale: 1,
        });
    });
    container.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
        if (!event.shiftKey) {
            return;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        instance.panBy({
            originX: event.movementX,
            originY: event.movementY
        });
    })
```

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.area {
    border: 1px dashed black;
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
}

.circle {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: navajowhite;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.rectangle {
    background-color: navajowhite;
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
}

.text-area {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="area">
            <div class="rectangle"></div>
            <div class="circle"></div>
            <div class="text-area">
                <h3>Example line of text</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cohen, thank you so much.  I appreciate you!!!